# Where did the Hungarian PM travel to & take this picture?

Tags: italy, identify-this, where-on-earth

The Hungarian PM decided to upload this image to his Facebook:

[image]

From other news, I know [he is in italy](https://hungarytoday.hu/pm-orban-meets-fratelli-ditalia-leader-in-rome/). I am interested in the specific location. Could you help?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: The FB post: https://www.facebook.com/orbanviktor/posts/384010416429896

Comment: This _really_ seems like a 'shop job. Is _any_ of it genuine?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-I was thinking exactly the same. The individuals seem very artificial, with a completely different color definition than the background and there are virtually no shadows under them.

Comment: Do you two mean that it is highly edited using PS, or he wasn't even there? If he wasn't, maybe we could find the original background picture?

Comment: @devouredelysium: It could be genuine. It does show several common signs of a bad Photoshop montage, such as the lack of shadows that you note, but sometimes real photos do look like that. In this case, the lack of definite shadows at least has an explanation: the foreground is all in the building's shadow. That's also why the background and foreground seem to have light coming from different directions. The odd colors might be Photoshop, but possibly just a selective color adjustment. And the weird poses of Orban and the guy with the pram make sense when you notice the strap Orban is holding.

Comment: The fakiness is a combination of phone camera filters (I’m guessing Samsung) and Instagram filter.

Comment: @chrylis: the fact it was uploaded to Orban’s own Facebook page suggests it’s less likely to be a photoshop.  Not impossible of course, but he has less obvious motive to fake such a picture than other people might, and more to lose if a fake was exposed.

Comment: Look at the artefacts around the wheels and frame of the child-carrier. None of them look realistic IMO.

Comment: Suggested edit: the trip is verified news

Comment: There is no way the hold that guy has on the buggy is strong enough to be holding it in the air like that. The edges of objects also look wrong. This image just screams "bad photoshop" to me.

Comment: And the feet also look totally wrong to me, I'm no photo analysis expert but if I was a betting man I would bet that at least the four people in the foreground were all edited in to the photo.

Comment: @PeterGreen you do realize that it's not just the guy holding up the buggy? The PM is holding the bottom part

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The pic was taken at [Villa Rufinella (AKA Villa Tuscolana), Frascati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villa_Rufinella), Italy. The steps leading upwards are also visible on [Google Streetview](https://goo.gl/maps/PfmozsYjdQHNKz8w9) (at the right):

[image]

Since another pic from the same date at the Hungarian PM's facebook page was taken in Rome (in front of Santa Maria sopra Minerva), this pic must haven been taken somewhere nearby. The shadows cast indicate that the view goes to the east or southeast; the hills in the background indicated a location east or south of Rome (Tivoli, Castel Gandolfo, Frascati). Google Streetview allowed to check possible buildings.